# What's job id limit for kue?

Tags: node.js, kue

My platform is nodejs and started using kue as the queue engine. It works perfectly so far and I'm just curious the max job id it allows, as I have billions of jobs per day to start with.

Answer (score 1):

it use Number for id so i think it's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` = 9007199254740991 or maybe `Number.MAX_VALUE`